# Data matching based on column and conditions

Tags: java, python, scala, pyspark, julia

I have two data sets with millions of Rows. The sample looks like below:

Data Set 1:

```
Row    col1 col2        col3
 1     A   01-01-1991   10
 2     B   02-01-1991   20
```

Data set 2:

```
Row    col1 col2        col3
 1     A   01-01-1991   -10
 2     B   02-01-1991   -10
 3     B   01-01-1991   -10
```

I want to match rows based on  col1 , col2 -with tolerance of 1 day and if sum of col3 equal to zero then generate a unique id against the data.

So base on the above rule the final result should look like this:

```
Data_set  Row    col1 col2        col3   Group_Id
    1      1     A   01-01-1991   -10     1
    2      1     A   01-01-1991    10     1 
    1      2     B   02-01-1991    20     2
    1      2     B   02-01-1991   -10     2
    1      3     B   01-01-1991   -10     2
```

I do not want any any code but ideas. I request you guys to point me towards a good logic to achieve this for a big data set. I am open to use Julia or pyspark or scala.

I have tried one logic :

To aggregate data base on col1 and col2 and then add col3 from both data set. This covers group id 1 but group 2 does not fall into this.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what constraints you have. But if you can sort data set 1 and data set 2 on `col1` and `col2` (in Julia you could do this e.g. using JuliaDB if data is too big to fit in RAM) then write a loop iterating over both sets to produce consecutive groups. There is no need to load whole data sets into RAM nor store the result in RAM to achieve this.

Comment: Thx @BogumiłKamiński for the comment, But how to capture the date tolerance one? also is there a Julia equivalent of  merge_asof() which is in python?

Comment: As I have proposed - if you have really large data that does not fit in memory use a `while` loop and move a cursor on both tables keeping track of start and end of two-day window in each table.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński juliadb is a good option. I was trying the filter function but i keep on getting this error: ERROR: MethodError: no method matching convert(::Type{Array{Bool,1}}, ::PooledArrays.PooledArray{Boo
l,UInt8,1,Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{Bool,1}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods. .... I am trying to filter on col1 ....filter(x -> x =="A", DataA,select=:col1)

Comment: Probably it would be good if you posted a separate question regarding this error with a minimal reproducible code as now it is hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

So julia has a [`isapporx` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/stdlib/math/#Base.isapprox), but this does not work for `Dates`.

You can, however, just subtract dates and check if the difference is less than 1.

```
using Dates
x = Date(2016, 07, 16)
y = Date(2016, 07, 13)
abs( x - y ) # 3 days
abs(x - y) <= Day(1) # false
```

For a big dataset, you may want to pre-allocate the new datatable first by finding out how many entries it will have, and then filling it in (Ie a two pass algorithm of your data)

```
using DataFrames
A = ... # dataframe 1
B = ... # dataframe 2
f(a::Date, b::Date) = abs(a-b) <= Day(1)
validrows = f.(A[:col2], B[:col2]) # a bitarray
sum(validrows) # number of rows that are within a day of each other
```

This assumes you are just comparing row `i` in dataset 1 with row `i` in dataset 2.
Then you can loop over the rows of both and "import" them into datset 3

```
C = DataFrame([Int, Int, Char, Date, ...], [:dataset, :row, :date, ...], sum(validrows))
for i in findall(validrows)
   C[i, :] = ... # your magic here 
end
```

Or whatever logic you need to have two rows per row in each database thats common...

Comment: Your solution assumes matching row by row, and in particular that both data sets have the same number of rows - which if I understand the problem correctly - is not the case. Additionally `DataFrame` is a good solution only if data is small (and I understood from the problem description that data does not fit in RAM).

Comment: For the row-by-row comment, that's true, and I said as much. Even if the comparison logic is more complicated, pre-allocating would likely be beneficial as the overhead for adding new rows could easily top the comparison/col3 logic
Moreover, DataFrames does run out of memory, true. But a couple million here and there can easily fit into most RAM, even on laptops. But point taken, `JuliaDB` would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is logical comparison with dates. I suggest you convert the dates to Julian Date format. Here is some code from Mathematica to help you.

```
ToJulianDayNumber[date_List] := Module[
  {year = date[[1]],
   month = date[[2]],
   day = date[[3]],
   a,
   y,
   m,
   result},
  a = Quotient[    14 - month, 12    ];
  y = year + 4800 - a;
  m = month + 12 * a - 3;
  result = 
   day + Quotient[    153* m + 2, 5    ] + 365 * y + 
    Quotient[    y, 4    ] - Quotient[    y, 100    ] + 
    Quotient[    y, 400    ] - 32045;
  result
  ]

FromJulianDayNumber[juliandaynum_Integer] := Module[
  {gnum, dgnum, cnum, dcnum, bnum,
   dbnum, anum, danum, ynum, mnum, dnum,
   yyyy, mm, dd, jnum, result},
  jnum = juliandaynum + 32044;
  gnum = Quotient[    jnum, 146097    ];
  dgnum = Mod[    jnum, 146097    ];
  cnum = (Quotient[    dgnum, 36524    ] + 1 ) * 3;
  cnum = Quotient[    cnum, 4    ];
  dcnum = dgnum - (cnum * 36524);
  bnum = Quotient[    dcnum, 1461    ];
  dbnum = Mod[    dcnum, 1461    ];
  anum = (Quotient[    dbnum, 365    ] + 1 ) * 3;
  anum = Quotient[    anum, 4    ];
  danum = dbnum - (anum * 365);
  ynum = gnum * 400 + cnum * 100 + bnum * 4 + anum;
  mnum = Quotient[(danum*5 + 308), 153] - 2; 
  dd = danum - Quotient[    (mnum + 4)*153, 5    ] + 123; 
  yyyy = ynum - 4800 + Quotient[    mnum + 2, 12    ];
  mm = Mod[  mnum + 2, 12  ] + 1;
  Return[{yyyy, mm, dd}]
  ]
```

Once you turned date into an integer number, it is much easier for you to do comparison anyway you want.